# pandoc markdown slides shown as a long html page

Tags: html, markdown, slideshow, pandoc

I am experimenting with markdown slides, using this example:

```
% My Lovely Title
% I am the author

# First Slide &#127758;

- bullet one
- bullet two
- bullet three

# Second Slide

- this is important
- this is not
```

When I generate the slideshow it appears in the browser (Firefox, Chrome) as a single html file

```
$ pandoc -t slidy -s slides.md -o slides.html
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is a markdown slide ?

Comment: I meant an html slideshow generated from a markdown file

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that with markdown. And what is it supposed to output ?

Comment: try the latest pandoc version and possibly `-t revealjs` instead of `-t slidy` yields better results... to debug the file pandoc generates, open your browser's developer tools and see that the right css/jss is loaded and not blocked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**: nothing was wrong with pandoc, it was completely the browser's fault.

Apparently, some browsers have a strict policy against running javascript in certain scenarios. I'm not exactly sure how to disable it, but the display as html slides is using javascript in a way that triggers heavy alarms in my browser, causing it to be displayed as one long html file.